# How to use default-character-set in django - mysql database connection

Tags: mysql, django, django-database, django-mysql

So, I was re-configuring my SQL and decided to move back from my.conf to settings.py (context: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#mysql-notes)

> '`read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',`
>
> ```
> # my.cnf
> [client]
> database = NAME
> user = USER
> password = PASSWORD
> default-character-set = utf8
> ```

So I was shifting from my.conf to settings.py I got an error

```
TypeError: 'default-character-set' is an invalid keyword argument for connect
```

My code:

```
'Options':{
      'default-character-set': utf8
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option  is charset

```
'Options':{
    'charset': 'utf8mb4'
}
```

Comment: Why it's different from the one in my.cnf?

Comment: as you error smessage stated, your option  'default-character-set' is not known, mybe it is because of the added white space, but i couldn't find any mention that such option exists, mine does, so use it and program after your hearts ontent

Comment: Using charset does work for me. I have tried removing the spaces it didn't work